# How to stop global mouse hooking using the command line

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line, console-application, mouseevent

I am researching how to execute and terminate a global mouse hook from the command line in a console application.

Below is the code I tried.

**Program.cs**

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {

         StartMonitoring();
         Application.Run(new ApplicationContext());
         string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
         while (userInput == null || !userInput.ToLower().Equals("quit"))
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Invalid command. Enter quit to exit...");
             userInput = Console.ReadLine();
         }

         StopMonitoring();
         Console.WriteLine("Exit!");
         Application.Exit();
 }

 private static void Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     MouseHook.MSLLHOOKSTRUCT temp = (MouseHook.MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)sender;

     switch (temp.MouseAction)
     {
         case "WM_LBUTTONDOWN":
             Console.WriteLine("Mouse Event Detected : " + temp.MouseAction + "\t Position : " + temp.pt.x + " " + temp.pt.y);

             // Call LeftClickHandler for left-click events
             ClickHandler(sender, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, temp.pt.x, temp.pt.y, 0), "Left Click");
             break;
         case "WM_RBUTTONDOWN":
             Console.WriteLine("Mouse Event Detected : " + temp.MouseAction + "\t Position : " + temp.pt.x + " " + temp.pt.y);

             // Call RightClickHandler for right-click events
             ClickHandler(sender, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Right, 1, temp.pt.x, temp.pt.y, 0), "Right Click");
             break;
         case "WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK":
             Console.WriteLine("Mouse Event Detected : " + temp.MouseAction + "\t Position : " + temp.pt.x + " " + temp.pt.y);

             // Call DblLeftClickHandler for double left-click events
             ClickHandler(sender, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, temp.pt.x, temp.pt.y, 0), "Double Click");
             break;
         default:
             Console.WriteLine("Unknown mouse event!");
             break;
     }
 }

 public static void StartMonitoring()
 {
     // Start mouse hook monitoring
     MouseHook.Start();
     MouseHook.MouseAction += new EventHandler(Event);
 }

 public static void StopMonitoring()
 {
     MouseHook.stop();
 }
```

**MouseHook.cs**

```
 using System;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace ProgramUsage
 {
     public static class MouseHook
     {
         public static event EventHandler MouseAction = delegate {};
         private delegate bool EnumChildProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);
         private static int clickCount = 0;
         private static Timer clickTimer = new Timer();
         private static int doubleClickInterval = SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime;
         private static IntPtr lastLParam;


         public static void Start()
         {
             _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
             clickTimer.Interval = doubleClickInterval;
             clickTimer.Tick += OnClickTimerTick;
         }
         public static void stop()
         {
             UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
         }

         private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
         private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

         private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
         {
             using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
             using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
             {
                 IntPtr hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle("user32"), 0);
                 if (hook == IntPtr.Zero) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
                 return hook;
             }
         }

         private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

         private static void sendCallback(IntPtr lParam, String s)
         {
            
             MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
             
             hookStruct.MouseAction = s;
             MouseAction(hookStruct, new EventArgs());
         }

         private static void OnClickTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             if (clickCount == 1)
             {
                 // Handle single-click
                 sendCallback(lastLParam, "WM_LBUTTONDOWN");
             }
             else if (clickCount >= 2)
             {
                 // Handle double-click
                 sendCallback(lastLParam, "WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK");
             }
             clickCount = 0;
             clickTimer.Stop();
         }

         private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
         {            
             if (nCode >= 0)
             {
                 if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
                 {
                     //sendCallback(lParam, "WM_LBUTTONDOWN");

                     MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));

                     // Create a copy of the MSLLHOOKSTRUCT structure
                     lastLParam = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)));
                     Marshal.StructureToPtr(hookStruct, lastLParam, false);

                     clickCount++;
                     if (clickCount == 1)
                     {
                         clickTimer.Start();
                     }
                 }
                 else if (MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
                 {
                     sendCallback(lParam, "WM_RBUTTONDOWN");
                 }
             }
             return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
         }


         private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

         private enum MouseMessages
         {
             WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
             WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
             WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203,
             WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
             WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
             WM_MOUSEWHEELDOWN = 0x0207,
             WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
             WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205,
             WM_CONTEXTMENU = 0x007B,
         }

         [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
         public struct POINT
         {
             public int x;
             public int y;
         }

         [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
         public struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
         {
             public POINT pt;
             public string MouseAction;
             public uint mouseData;
             public uint flags;
             public uint time;
             public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
         }

         [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
         private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
           LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

         [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
         [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
         private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

         [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
         private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
           IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

         [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
         private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
     }
 }
```

If I do this, the global mouse hook will run after the program is executed, but I cannot enter any commands until it is forcibly stopped.

```
Application.Run(new ApplicationContext());
```

If I comment out this part, I can enter command lines, but there will be significant lag and mouse event will not be captured.

Can anyone kindly tell me what I did wrong?